# Why MySQL return column name with quotes?

Tags: mysql, database, quotes

i have this:

```
...
SELECT 
    `id`, 
    `name`, 
    `user_id`, 
    `xml_tables`
...
```

and when making the query, I recive this:

```
+- ----+------+---------+------------+
| `id` | name | user_id | xml_tables |
+------+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | name |       1 |        xml |
+------+------+---------+------------+
```

with the name of the ID column with quotes.

Comment: I've never seen MySQL do this. What is the environment you see this in?

Comment: im working with MySQL 5.7.19-log, and i do the query in Workbench.
[link](http://prntscr.com/h99dln)

Comment: this stops happening if I put the name of the table before: `table_name`.`id`

Comment: They are not quotes they are backticks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are calling a stored procedure. But you haven't shown the code in your procedure.

I tried to recreate the issue:

```
mysql> create procedure sp_read_database(in i int)
    -> begin
    -> select 123 as `id`, 'name' as `name`, 456 as `user_id`, 'xml tables' as `xml_tables`;
    -> end
```

Then call the procedure in MySQL Workbench 6.3.9:

[image]

I don't see any back-ticks around the `id` column in the result grid.

I suspect your procedure contains some errant code formatting. I can reproduce your results if I add literal back-ticks to my column alias for `id`:

````
mysql> create procedure sp_read_database(in i int)
    -> begin
    -> select 123 as ```id```, 'name' as `name`, 456 as `user_id`, 'xml tables' as `xml_tables`;
    -> end
````

[image]

Comment: Yip that is the case.

Comment: it was due to rare characters in SP, I had to clean it

Answer (score 1):

These are not the quotes you are looking for.

Those are single quotes they look like this:

```
'HELLO'
```

Those are backticks or:

```
`HELLO`
```

MySQL uses backticks as delimiters around columns names. They are not part of the name just here for display.

This helps when you use a reserved word such as GROUP as a columns name.
This will fail:

```
 SELECT Group
 FROM   UserGroup
```

This will run

```
SELECT `Group`
FROM   UserGroup
```

If you ran a create statement like the following you might have included the backticks as part of the name:

````
CREATE TABLE `log` 
(
    ```log_id``` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `log_text` LONGTEXT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (```log_id```)

)
````